# Error "no multiboot header found" when trying to compile my own os

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86, osdev

I have written a bare bones OS in c with an assembly bootloader but I cannot get it to run, every time i run it I get the error "no multiboot header found" from grub2. I know my code isn't the problem, I have tried to compile other OS's and they give the same error. System specs: Ubuntu Linux with gcc version 7.2. I have already looked at all the other questions about this and none of them have worked for me.

Im using these commands to compile my OS:

```
as boot.s -o boot.o

gcc -c kernel.c -o kernel.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra

gcc -T linker.ld -o MyOS.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib kernel.o boot.o -lgcc

grub-file --is-x86-multiboot MyOS.bin

mkdir -p isodir/boot/grub
cp MyOS.bin isodir/boot/MyOS.bin
cp grub.cfg isodir/boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkrescue -o MyOS.iso isodir

qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom MyOS.iso
```

bootloader:

```
    # set magic number to 0x1BADB002 to identified by bootloader   
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002  

# set flags to 0  
.set FLAGS,    0  

# set the checksum  
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)  

# set multiboot enabled  
.section .multiboot  

# define type to long for each data defined as above  
.long MAGIC  
.long FLAGS  
.long CHECKSUM  


# set the stack bottom   
stackBottom:  

# define the maximum size of stack to 512 bytes  
.skip 512  


# set the stack top which grows from higher to lower  
stackTop:  

.section .text  
.global _start  
.type _start, @function  


_start:  

  # assign current stack pointer location to stackTop  
    mov $stackTop, %esp  

  # call the kernel main source  
    call KERNEL_MAIN  

    cli  


# put system in infinite loop  
hltLoop:  

    hlt  
    jmp hltLoop  

.size _start, . - _start
```

linker:

```
/* The bootloader will look at this image and start execution at the symbol designated at the entry point. */
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    /* Begin putting sections at 1 MiB, a conventional place for kernels to be
       loaded at by the bootloader. */
    . = 1M;

    /* First put the multiboot header, as it is required to be put very early in the image or the bootloader won't recognize the file format. Next we'll put the .text section. */
    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
    }

    /* Read-only data. */
    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    /* Read-write data (initialized) */
    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    /* Read-write data (uninitialized) and stack */
    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
        *(.bootstrap_stack)
    }
}
```

kernel:

```
#include"kernel.h"  

static UINT16 VGA_DefaultEntry(unsigned char to_print) {  
    return (UINT16) to_print | (UINT16)WHITE_COLOR << 8;  
}  

void KERNEL_MAIN()  
{  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER = (UINT16*) VGA_ADDRESS;  

  TERMINAL_BUFFER[0] = VGA_DefaultEntry('H');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[1] = VGA_DefaultEntry('e');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[2] = VGA_DefaultEntry('l');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[3] = VGA_DefaultEntry('l');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[4] = VGA_DefaultEntry('o');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[5] = VGA_DefaultEntry(' ');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[6] = VGA_DefaultEntry('W');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[7] = VGA_DefaultEntry('o');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[8] = VGA_DefaultEntry('r');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[9] = VGA_DefaultEntry('l');  
  TERMINAL_BUFFER[10] = VGA_DefaultEntry('d');  
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have a linker script that places the multiboode header at the top (It needs to be in the first 8kb of the ELF executable you generate and be aligned on a 4byte boundary). If using a 64-bit GCC compiler (it is preferred you use an i686 or i385 cross compiler) then you'll need to link with `-z max-page-size=4096` (I assume you are linking with GCC) and use `-m32` if creating a 32-bit kernel. It would help if you showed us your linker script, and your multiboot assembly file and the commands you use to link and compile.

Comment: Its not my code, I explained that in my post, I have tried compiling other OS's that should work but the multiboot issue happens to them too.

Comment: Please show the commands you are using to compile your custom loader, and how you are linking the binary. You may need to show the code you wrote.

Comment: My best guess from what you posted is that you are compiling a 32-bit kernel as a 64-bit program. Use  `-m32` on your GCC command lines for compiling and linking. This is a guess because you don't actually show us `boot.s`

Comment: Okay now show us your `linker.ld` .Showing the linker script is also important so weknow the `.multiboot` section is placed first. The other thing you may have to do is on the GCC linker command line specify `-Wl,--build-id=none` and `-N`

Comment: Thanks for posting those files. Now in my comments above start by adding `-m32` to all the GCC commands to force 32-bit compilation (as you are writing a 32-bit kernel so far). With the `as` command you will have to add `--32` . On the GCC line that does the linking also add `-Wl,--build-id=none`

Comment: That worked! Now there is a new problem. As soon as i click on it from GRUB it exits back to grub also I can't use the -m32 flag because my gcc is x64

Comment: Okay if it exits back to GRUB that means the program likely triple faulted and caused the virtual machine to reboot (and rerun the bootloader). You will probably have to show us your `kernel.c`

Comment: I get this error when i use the -m32 flag:

`/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Try installing `gcc-multilib` with `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`

Comment: that didn't make a difference

Comment: Did you add `--32` to the `as` command and `-m32` to each `gcc` line? Can tell you unless you build this as 32-bit you won't be getting anywhere. For now remove `-lgcc` as your current code doesn't need it

Comment: I added that but it didn't fix it

Comment: It works :)!!!!

Comment: If you ever want to build a cross compiler OSDev Wiki has instructions: https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: I think the header is insufficient for x86 elf kernel. You should see [how James implements it](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/2.-Genesis.html)